# Attempting to save password and username in Android studio with sharedpreferences, pass to new activity and display

Tags: android

I'm working on my first Android Studio app. I need to be able to access the username and password on each activity to request specific data from the server. Currently, I am attempting to save the username and password on the MainActivity with SharedPreferences so I can access them in other apps. I have been unsuccessful in displaying them in other apps, which leads me to believe I am saving them or referencing them incorrectly.

I've attempted moving the sharedPreferences code around in the MainActivity and the ProfileActivity, as well as trying various syntax forms. When I run the app the ProfileActivity page pops up with two textView boxes. Both have "textView" in them, which is what makes me think the boxes aren't even being set correctly.

Please help me with this elementary step. Thanks

MainActivity:

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
public static final String Password = "passwordKey";

EditText usernameField, passwordField;
Button button;

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
//identify fields where you are pulling in info from user
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    usernameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    passwordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);


}

public void loginGet (View view) {
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(Name, usernameField.toString());
    editor.putString(Password, passwordField.toString());
    editor.commit();

    new SigninActivity(this).execute(usernameField.toString(), passwordField.toString());

}
```

}

The sharedpreference strings should be displayed in textView5 and textView 8, but nothing registers.

ProfileActivity:

```
private String usernameField, passwordField;

//Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
//String[] array = b.getStringArray(null);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String username = sharedpreferences.getString("nameKey", "notfound");
    String password = sharedpreferences.getString("passwordKey", "notfound");

    TextView textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    textView5.setText("testing");
    textView8.setText("ya!!");

}
```

}

Comment: so make a common class where you can save your Shared Preference

Comment: see my answer below. It will show proper results.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 editor.putString(Name, usernameField.toString());
 editor.putString(Password, passwordField.toString());
```

with

```
editor.putString(Name, usernameField.getText().toString());
editor.putString(Password, passwordField.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Good catch, however the username and password are still not showing up in the textView5 and textView8. Even hardcoded values in the setText() method are not changing, which makes me think something is going on with setText().

Comment: set String value you are getting from SharedPreferences to TextView

Comment: replace your hard-coded values in setText() with variables **username** and **password**

Comment: I changed them back - no change.

Comment: replace **PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)** 
 with **getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)** in ProfileActivity

Answer (score 0):

your edit text should be `edittext.getText().toString();`
Change your profile activity.`private String usernameField, passwordField;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = sharedpreferences.getString("nameKey", "notfound");
String password = sharedpreferences.getString("passwordKey", "notfound");

TextView textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
textView5.setText("testing");
textView8.setText("ya!!");

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
editor.putString(Name, usernameField.toString());
editor.putString(Password, passwordField.toString());
```

You're gettting the string of the `TextField` **object**, not the value of what's **in the textfield**.

To retrieve values from textfields use `TextField.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Lazy and Easy way......Mantain Excel sheet for every key of sharedpreference 

    // initialize shared preference

     SharedPreferences sp= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    // save values

    public void savePreference(String KEY,String VALUE) {
  SharedPreferences sp= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor mEditor = sp.edit();
        mEditor.putString(KEY, VALUE);
        mEditor.commit();
    }

    // retrive values

    String Name=sp.getString("KEY","");  // if value is already present than u will get value otherwise you will get ""
```

Answer (score 0):

To get Text from an `EditText` you have to use `EditText.getText()` method.

**Update your `loginGet()` method as below:**

```
public void loginGet (View view) {
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(Name, usernameField.getText().toString());
    editor.putString(Password, passwordField.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

    new SigninActivity(this).execute(usernameField.toString(), passwordField.toString());

}
```

**To show `username` and `password` on `ProfileActivity`:**

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String Name = "nameKey"; 
public static final String Password = "passwordKey";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = sharedpreferences.getString(Name, "notfound");
    String password = sharedpreferences.getString(Password, "notfound");

    TextView textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    textView5.setText(username);
    textView8.setText(password);

}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into mine, but the data still does not show up in the textViews.

Comment: Try my updated answer. Use getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) also in ProfileActivity as you have saved username and password to MyPrefs. Copy profile activity and try again. FYI, always try to put some logs for this kind of cases. Hope this will help